# I get this Error: Invalid src prop {theLink} on `next/image`, hostname "image.tmdb.org" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`

Tags: next.js

I have configured the `next.config.js` as per the docs for next13 but it is not working. I am using the Movie DB API.

Here's my code:

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'image.tmdb.org',
        port: '',
        pathname: '/t/p/original',
      },
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: did u restart the app after u configured the `next.config.js`

Comment: So I found the fix. Apparently I was supposed to add /** in the pathname. Like this: pathname: '/t/p/original/**'